# Laravel Passeport change user email authentication to username

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-api

I am building a Laravel App as API using React. i want to change the default authentication field 'email' to 'username' field when using the passport grant Oauth. what is the best way to do that without changing the Laravel AuthenticatesUser trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your User model, you can add this following method to login by username instead of email :

```
/**
 * Find the user instance for the given username.
 *
 * @param  string  $username
 * @return \App\User
 */
public function findForPassport($username)
{
    return $this->where('username', $username)->first();
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#customizing-the-username-field